# save a picture taken by Raspberry pi to a mounted NAS

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mount, nas

I am trying to take a photo with a RasberryPi Zero and save it to my mounted NAS instead of locally to the SDcard to prevent wear out.

In my python code I have

```
os.system('sudo mount -t cifs -o guest //WDMYCLOUD/Public /home/pi/photo_prog/WD_drive')
```

I was worried using `sudo` but without `sudo` I could not successfully mount the drive for user pi

Then later in my code I take the photo

```
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
     camera.resolution = (1280, 720)   
     camera.capture('/home/pi/photo_prog/WD_drive/image{0:04d}.jpg'.format(i+motion_set))
```

I then get a permissions denied error during runtime. Are there better ways to go about this?

Comment: It depends whether your motivation is purely to save disk writes or to get the image to your NAS. If you don't really need the image on your NAS, you could make a memory-based filesystem on your RasPi and write your image there https://domoticproject.com/extending-life-raspberry-pi-sd-card/

Comment: Thank you for the tip Mark.  This is a great link and something I can use.  In this case I did want to get the image to my NAS.  I did find a way to fix the permissions issue I was having but it gets into permissions management which due to my inexperience I worry I am creating a bigger problem down the road.  This is the change I made to get it working.    ``sudo mount -t cifs -o guest,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 //WDMYCLOUD/Public /home/pi/photo_prog/WD_drive``